# A justification for remote code use is required. - Chrome Extenstion

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Extension is not getting published because of 2 error

- A justification for remote code use is required.
- The single purpose description is required.

Here's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Spotlight",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png",
    "96": "icon.png"
  },
  "description": "Spotlight - Browse open tabs, search history, bookmarks, downloads, and do much more!",
  "version": "1.19",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [],
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "homepage_url": "https://usespotlight.co",
  "optional_permissions" : [ 
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "history",
    "downloads",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }, 
  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+M",
        "mac": "Command+M"
       },
      "description": "Toggle spotlight"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure about the "justification" word ?

Comment: yes. It's what google is showing me

Comment: can we have the google search ?

Comment: By google, I meant chrome webstore developer console. Here the screenshot - https://pasteboard.co/ITVq4QX.png

Comment: seems you are missing thoses 2 fields in the manifest. A description of reasons why you have to use remote code, and a summary of your extension. Not sure about that although

Comment: There's no such option coming in developer guide for chrome manifest file format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Go to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/` then click on  Privacy menu (3th tab on the left) then fill all your purpose description. After that you can release your extension normally

Answer (score 5):

You have to go to the new developer dashboard and fill out these fields under the Privacy menu.

Answer (score 0):

These new requirements are not actually part of the manifest. In the new developer console, click your item and go to the privacy tab. You can find the various requirements there.
ActiveTab - Used to open tabs
Host Permission - Used to load files onto certain websites

> ```
>  "matches": [
>    "https://www.google.com/"
>  ],
>  "js": [
>    "googleHome.js"
>  ]
> ```

Single purpose description is an old suggestion and a new requirement. Just now being enforced because extensions are supposed to be small and serve a single purpose.